# Why doesn't the Intensity of laser light drop by $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$?

Tags: visible-light, laser, intensity

If we observe a laser we see its intensity wont drop by $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ as seen for regular light sources as its very concentrated and even remain somewhat same for long distances (even though its projection is a small circle as would the large projection of a $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ light source is a circle)

Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: The intensity does drop like 1/r*2. Just because the light is spreading out in a smaller solid angle than 4pi doesn't change the distance dependence in the far field, neither for light from thermal sources or for light generated by a laser. The laser light is simply spatially more coherent and can therefor be focused in a tight beam, while the incoherent light from a thermal source does not allow us to do this.

Comment: The intensity DOES fall off as 1/r^2.  If it remained the same over any distance you would violate the uncertainty principle.

Comment: It is necessary to take into account the shape of one of the two mirrors of the optical cavity :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_cavity#:~:text=An%20optical%20cavity%2C%20resonating%20cavity,feedback%20of%20the%20laser%20light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power does drop off as $1/r^2$, at least if you are not too close to the output aperture.

If the output is focused, then beyond the focal plane the beam will begin to diverge. If the output is collimated, then beyond the [*Rayleigh range*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Rayleigh_range_and_confocal_parameter) of the beam, the beam will diverge.

As the beam diverges, its diameter increases linearly with distance. And therefore the cross-sectional area increases with the square of distance. But the same power is delivered across that area. Therefore the intensity must fall as $1/r^2$.

Comment: The Photon, given your name, it's "classic" that you would give the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The law of inverse squared distance ($ I\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$) for light intensity holds in general for distances $r$ that are many times larger than size of the light source, or in special case, it holds for all distances if the source has spherical symmetry - then it produces approximately the same intensity of radiation in all directions (Sun, or a very hot glowing metal ball).

Laser light is not the same intensity in all directions, it's the opposite. So laser light weakens as $1/r^2$ only if $r$ is large enough compared to width of the light beam. Closer to the aperture, it weakens with distance in a different way, more slowly.

When the point of study is close enough to the source of light (bulb, LED, hot metal plate, laser device), distance $r$ is not many times larger than size of the source, and intensity may decay more slowly there. For example, if the light source is planar (hot metal plate), for small enough distances from it, light intensity does not decrease with distance at all.

Answer (score 0):

Only point sources, or almost point sources have the 1/r^2 behavior, laser light is almost parallel, with point sources you reach the same effect , if you place them in the focus of a concave mirror, like the headlights in a car.

Comment: Of course, if the distance is large enough, every source is a point source. So, if you get far enough from your laser, it'll drop by $1/r^2$.

Comment: But that doesn't change the long distance behavior of intensity. Perfectly parallel beams can not exist because of diffraction and therefor even laser beam intensity will fall with distance..

Comment: @John Doty  If the distance is large enough, every point source is a point source but it doesn't necessarily radiate uniformly in all directions. I thought that was the condition for the 1/r^2 falloff of power per unit area.

Comment: @Not_Einstein It suffices to be far enough away from the light source that the rays are spreading out as if they came from a point.